# Apps opens wrong browser

Tags: 20.04, firefox, .desktop, default-browser

I recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu finally. I am using Firefox as my default browser.

When I click on links in some apps (e.g. Slack), they won't open the site in the opened window of Firefox. They'll create a new one where I am not signed in. It is not opened as a browser, Slack opens Firefox inside itself:

[image: Screenshot]

I have no idea how to fix this, and I cannot find similar problems on the internet.

Hope you can help me!

Comment: Your Image is very small, can you make it bigger?

Comment: The image just shows that the Firefox Browser is opened as Slack. It's a screenshot from the taskbar, can't make it bigger :(

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Go to your `Home` directory.
2. Press <kbd>Ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show all hidden files.
3. Then go to the `.local/share/applications` folder and delete the mime files.
4. Restart the computer and check the result.